Swift UITableView stuttered when scene was loaded and disappearing, only on iOS 18
I have an original iOS app written in Xcode 15, Swift 5.10 on macOS Sonoma, everything worked fine.
ISSUE
After updating to Xcode 16.0 and Swift 6 on macOS 15.0, problem occurred. When compiling app on iPhone simulator with iOS 18.0, the UITableView stuttered / jumped up and down right after the view is loaded by tapping the tap bar item.
Attached Video here:
Left side: normal animation on iPhone SE simulator (iOS 17.5)
Right side: stuttered view on iPhone SE simulator (iOS 18)
TROUBLESHOOTING
Attempts:

Created a completely empty project to replicated the issue. On a storyboard, a UITabBarController was linked with two UITableViewController as two tab items. Compiled program on iPhone SE simulator and problem prevailed.
Changed Target's minimum deployment version to iOS 15.6 then
recompiled program on iPhone SE simulator with iOS 17.5 and no issue
presented.
Tried iPhone 16 (iOS 18) and iPad simulators, problem only
exists on iOS 18 on both iPhone and iPad.
Tested on a real iPhone 13 (iOS 18) but it has the same issue.
Tried adjusting the row and header heights and their estimates but no
luck.
Tried disabling scrolling in the tableview. The view will snap to the top of screen as shown below, but the stutter disappeared together with the scrolling:


Attached Test project
Mac version: Mac Mini M2 with macOS 15.0.1 (24A348)
Xcode version: 16.0 (16A242d)
Still new to Swift. Thanks for any help!
EDIT:
This and this are suspected to be a related issue.

Minor update: the issue on my real device iPhone 13 iOS 18.0 disappeared for an hour and then popped up again. There was no changes on the phone nor modification / re-installation of the app. It is getting more like a bug of iOS 18 IMO.

Please provide a [mcve] (not a download from some shared drive; no one is going to click that link). — If you think you've found a runtime issue introduced in iOS 18, please report it to Apple as a bug report. There is unlikely to be anything we can do about it.
